# Rails Active Storage not uploading files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activestorage

I am totally new to `Ruby On Rails`. I was trying to make an application where I can upload files to local storage. I am using `ActiveStorage`. After performing all the steps I am unable to upload the file. I am sharing the codes that might be needed to help me out.

> 1. new.html.ebr

```
<h1>Add New Post</h1>
<%= form_for @test do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :file %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :file %><br>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Add Post" %><br>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

> 2. test_controller.rb

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
    @test = Test.new
  end

  def create
    @test = Test.new(test_params)
    if @test.save
      redirect_to tests_path
    else
      redirect_to "new"
    end
  end

  def test_params
    params.require(:test).permit(:title, :file)
  end
end
```

> 3. test.rb

```
class Test < ApplicationRecord
    has_one_attached :file
end
```

> 4. model-migration-code (just in case)

```
class CreateTests < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :tests do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :file

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

After submitting the form only the `tests` table is updated. The value in the `file` column is `#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000000d5bec50>` not the file path. And the tables `active_storage_attachments and active_storage_blobs` that is needed to get updated are not updated.

- I am using **PostgreSQL V10.x** as my Database.
- **Ruby version - ruby 2.5.3p105**
- **Rails version - Rails 5.1.7**

Edit: I am adding the log for some more info

> Started POST "/tests" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-05-31 12:25:25 +0530
>   Processing by TestsController#create as HTML
>   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"W9EE8ot+SzsJQMzgQ6gVWqER2TIXN2mUW7PBgTt0DV8mskeR2oGO/iHTx+quBT0cXTLobU60SoFsceNOzA8+2Q==",
>   "test"=>{"title"=>"sss", "file"=>#'<'ActionDispatch::Http:
>   :UploadedFile:0x000000000d0a25c8>
>   @tempfile=#,
>   @original_filename="contacts.vcf", @content_type="text/x-vcard", @head
>   ers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"test[file]\";
>   filename=\"contacts.vcf\"\r\nContent-Type: text/x-vcard\r\n">},
>   "commit"=>"Add Post"}
>   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
>   SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "tests" ("title", "file", "created_at",
>   "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["title",
>   "sss"], ["file", "#"], ["created_at", "2019-05-31 06:55:25.837658"],
>   ["updated_at", "2019-05-31 06:55:25.837658"]]
>   (26.6ms)  COMMIT
>   Redirected to http://localhost:3000/tests
>   Completed 302 Found in 34ms (ActiveRecord: 27.5ms)

**Can anyone say whether this issue is because of rails version ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Follow](https://www.agiratech.com/active-storage-in-rails-5-2/) this link. Still if you have any problem then let me know.

Comment: check with `Test.first.file.attached?` and ihope you have added initials by using `rails active_storage:install`

Comment: Since you are using ActiveStorage there shouldn't be a `file` column in the tests table

Comment: @ray: Yes I have added the initials, but for me, it was `rails activestorage:install`. And I am trying your suggestion about the checking.

Comment: @kishorecheruku: I think I have done the same as the post you refered suggested. Then also, not working.

Comment: @Mark Merritt: First I did the model without the file column, it throw en error `unknown attribute 'file' for Upload.`, to resolve this I added in the Model class `upload.rb` => `attr_accessor :title, :file`. The results remain the same.

Comment: Is the code on the question your current code? if so remove the "file" column from the tests table.

Comment: @arieljoud: I did as u r suggesting. Please refer to my reply to Mark Merritt